# How to display a menu and a panel in the same window in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I've got a JMenu and I want to change the window's content according to what button from the menu is pressed. I managed to show the panel as a popup, but I want it to be displayed in the same window with the menu. This is my code so far :

```
public class GUImenu extends JFrame


{
      private JMenuBar menuBar;   
       private JMenu menu;          
       private JMenu subMenu;    
       private JMenuItem item1;
       private JMenuItem item2;
       private JMenuItem item3;
       private JMenuItem item4;
       private JMenuItem item5;
       private JMenuItem item6;

       public GUImenu()
       {
          super("Example Menu System");// Call the JFrame constructor.
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   // Specify an action for the close button.
          buildMenuBar();

          // Pack and display the window.
          pack();
          setSize(1000, 250); // set frame size
          setVisible(true);
       }

       private void buildMenuBar()
       {
          // Create the menu bar.
          menuBar = new JMenuBar();

          // Create the file and text menus.
          menu = new JMenu("Menu"); menuBar.add(menu);
          subMenu = new JMenu("Create Customer");
          item1 = new JMenuItem("Ordinary Customer"); subMenu.add(item1);
          item1.addActionListener(new showOrdinaryCust());
          item6 = new JMenuItem("Privileged Customer"); subMenu.add(item6);

          menu.add(subMenu);
          item2 = new JMenuItem("View Customers Who Didn't Pay"); menu.add(item2);
          item3 = new JMenuItem("Remove Client");menu.add(item3);
          item4 = new JMenuItem("Create Order"); menu.add(item4);
          item5 = new JMenuItem("Search..."); menu.add(item5);
          setJMenuBar(menuBar);

       }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          new GUImenu();
       }
       private class showOrdinaryCust implements ActionListener
       {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
          {
              if(event.getSource()==item1)
                  GUIpanel.main(null);

          }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I would try to fill the entire window with a CardLayout. CardLayout is meant to switch its contents between separate views. Simply set up multiple cards for each of the panels you want to show and have the menu switch between them.

Comment: +1, All that's required is an appropriate layout manager, and you found it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows or dialogs you will latter have to deal with the focus, the closing, minimizing, maximizing, re-size, centering, visibility...
In your case i would recommend you to pick a good layout to suit your needs(Probably the easiest way to achieve your goal).

What do you think about tabbed panes?
See this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Answer (score 1):

building guis is a little complex, but worth the time spent to understand what options are.  This is a good place to start as it explains various java gui layouts, including using a layout manager.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html.

For future posts, your example should be complete, including imports so we can copy and paste code, compile and look at.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple enough. I have implemented this thing as follows :

First get content pane of your JFrame, say in container. Make this container object static.

```
private static Container container;
```

now get content pane.

```
container = this.getContentPane();
```

Now on click on menu call some method that will do some thing like this :

```
container.removeAll();
container.add(new JPanel());   //Add object of your panel you want to show.
container.revalidate();
```

This method is helpful in case you want to show multiple panels in same JFrame.

Comment: -1, container.revalidate() should be used to tell the container that component have been removed/added. Don't play with visibility.